# Comparisons between objects

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, comparison

If you have tower A and tower B, and you know that they both have the same number of floors.

So complete the following sentence:

> Tower A has the same number of floors ______ Tower B

Well obviously it should be "as," but can't it be also "of"?

Comment: No, it can't be *of*; only *as* works there. Think of extending or completing the sentence with the elided *does*: "*Tower A had the same number of floors **of** Tower B [does]*"? No. All that said, the proper venue for this type of question (and any follow-ups you might have to this question) is our sister site, [ELL.se].

Comment: I will just wait for more answers because I feel that it could be right (Strange how sometimes think It is ridiculous).
Thanks for answering though. :)

Comment: Dan is unquestionably correct, so if you get any answers saying otherwise than they would be incorrect and would defy English syntax. "As" is comparative, where as "of" pertains to something being a part of something else. The two towers have similarities but no other indicated relationship otherwise which is why "of" is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

Dan is right. It cannot be "of".

Comparisons are done with "as".